# How to make auto increment in textbox vb.net my database is Access

Tags: ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I want to my ID in textbox increase by one every time I finish registration and click the button ADD.

Here's my code

```
Try
   cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & Application.StartupPath & "\HMSdb.accdb")
        cn.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from PatientRegistration ", cn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            txtPatientID.Text = dr.Item(0) + 1
        Else
            txtPatientID.Text = "1"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Is my code correct or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get ID(auto increment) in access and display in textbox vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568260/how-can-i-get-idauto-increment-in-access-and-display-in-textbox-vb-net)